# Are there any pre built home page design/template in Rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

for home page of my app, I am looking to have a standard SaaS page for the time being but don't want to build it from scatch and was wondering if rails community has something. Any kind of pre built design or template will do it for me

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Twitter Bootstrap as a framework then you could check out [Built With Bootstrap](http://builtwithbootstrap.com/).

As Bootstrap uses SASS and LESS there may be some examples in there for you, and also check out the premuim section within the same site, most templates are around $12-$15 dollars.